# SQL: LIKE and Contains — Different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Express SQL function `Contains` to select data. However when I selected data with LIKE operator, I realised that Contains function is missing a few rows.

Rebuilt indexes but it didn't help.

Sql:  `brs.SearchText like '%aprilis%'` and `CONTAINS(brs.SearchText, '*aprilis*')`

The `contains` function missed rows like:

```
22-28.aprīlis
[1.aprīlis]
Sīraprīlis
```

PS. If I search directly `CONTAINS(brs.SearchText, '*22-28.aprīlis*')`, then it finds them

Comment: Since the text contains U+012B LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH MACRON rather than U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I, it is reasonable to guess that one of the functions/operators is disregarding accents and the other is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`contains` is functionality based on the full text index.  It supports words, phrases, and prefixed matches on words, but not suffixed matches.  So you can match words that start with `'aprilis'` but not words that end with it or that contain it arbitrarily in the middle.  You might be able to take advantage of a thesaurus for these terms.

This is explained in more detail in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).